# iOS - Youtube Player Controller Bar Color while in Full Screen

Tags: ios, ios6, youtube

I have embed youtube in a view using UIWebView.

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <body style=\"margin:0;\"><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", self.view.bounds.size.width - kTitleLabelLeftIndent*2, kUIWebViewHeight, self.utubeId];

utubeWebView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
[utubeWebView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES]; 
[utubeWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

The youtube URL is well embedded in my app. And when I hit the Play button on the utudeWebView it shows a fullscreen like this:

[image]

where the Red Controller Bar on top is not looking good.Could somebody tell me how can I change the color of that bar?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out why was it red now.

In my AppDelegate, I have set the appearance of NavigationBar:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I didn't notice the relationship between navigationBar and video control bar because I had my navigationBar set hidden.

Somehow, the setting of navigationBar's color would also affect the color of the MPmoviePlayerController's control bar. So setting the NavigationBar's Tint Color, I could change the color of the control bar. Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]